# I'm trying to create a custom $PS1 that shows how many files I have in each directory I'm in and print the results

Tags: linux, bash

Here's what i came up with, but when I'm change directory the results doesn't change and displayed my $HOME dir results

Example:

```
export PS1="\n\[$Blue\](\[$Red\]\u\[$White\] @
\[$Red\]$(hostname)\[$Blue\])---(\[$Green\]\w\[$Blue\])\n(\[$Green\]$(ls
-1 |wc -l) files\[$Blue\])<<--^\n\[$BRed\]\$\[\033[0m\]"
```

I thought that maybe to add this but I don't know how to.

> ```
> for file in $PWD
>  do   echo `ls -1 |wc -l` 
>  done
> ```

Can someone help?

Comment: what u have got is correct. just change the option to ls from -1 to -l

Comment: @euphoria83, no, `-1` is the correct option.

Comment: you are right, @glennjackman. my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful to delay executing the `ls` command until the prompt is delayed. As it stands now, it is executed when you define PS1

```
part1="\n[$Blue]([$Red]\u[$White] @ [$Red]$(hostname)[$Blue])---([$Green]\w[$Blue])"
part2="\n([$Green]"'$(ls -1 |wc -l)'" files[$Blue])<<--^"
part3="\n[$BRed]\\\$[\033[0m]"
export PS1="${part1}${part2}${part3}"
unset part1 part2 part3
```

Note the mix of single and double quotes in `part2`

---

A second thought: for safety from files containing newlines, the counting code can be

```
$(files=(*); echo "${#files[@]}")       # "visible" files only
# or
$(f=(* .[^.] .??*); echo "${#f[@]}")    # includes hidden files, not . or ..
```

That stores the filenames in an array and prints out the size of the array. Also that only uses bash builtin commands.

Comment: If you **truly** want to know how many files, add the `-A` option to `ls`

Comment: I would also add the `-U` option to avoid the overhead of sorting.

Comment: Use `shopt -s dotglob nullglob`, then `f=(*)` will include everything except `.` and `..`, as well as handling empty directories.

Answer (score 0):

include

```
\$(ls -l | wc -l)
```

anywhere within your PS1

Answer (score 0):

I would use `find` instead of `ls` to count the files to ensure that if a filename contains linebreaks it is not counted multiple times. So I would do something like that:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf 1 | wc -c
```

You can put it inside the definition os `PS1` like so:

```
PS1='... $(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf 1 | wc -c) ...'
```